# Elastic Beanstalk - auto scaling - grace-period

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a eb env setup and the auto scaling works hunky dory. The problem I have is that when a news instance starts up the db connection does not work. I think this is because the 'new' instance is not quite ready yet but the as far the auto scaling mechanism is concerned it is healthy as it can be pinged.

I have read that you can set a grace period for the instances to give them longer to start up before they are required as described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html

So my question is this - what is 'Auto Scaling group name' if you use eb to set everything up.

Is this actually my problem?

I am using wordpress (php 5.4 in EB) - I get the ' Error establishing a database connection' error on the new instances.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted in your answer, the AWS console does not offer a lot of insight into Auto Scaling. In addition to the Python tool, you can also use the shell tool:

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2535

Each instance created by an auto scaling group is tagged, and just by looking at the instance tags in the console you can see what the group name is.

It sounds like you are using an EC2 health check, rather than an ELB health check? The EC2 check reports the instance healthy as soon as the instance finishes booting. an ELB health check waits until the check specified by your ELB passes.

You would need to create an ELB health check that requires that the application is up and running.

The grace period allows you to give the application time to get started, and also prevents an auto scaling event if an instance hiccups for a second and drops out of the load balancer.

If you go that route, in order to change the auto scaling group setup, you'll need to use the API, as you can't do that from the console.

Comment: I have tried this - the problem is that the elb starts using the server before its connected to the db so during this process I get 500  errors which are ok as eventually they go and the instance becomes 'healthy'

Comment: It sounds like you would need to change the health check on your ELB to actually hit a page on your site that will fail if the server is not fully up. 

That will prevent the server from joining the ELB until the health check page can be loaded.

Comment: the database error page appears and returns a 500 error which should mean the server is not healthy? But it still appears.

Answer (score 0):

well - I have found the 'Auto Scaling group name'. If you install awscli(http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and do:

```
aws ec2 --region 'your-region' describe-instances
```

you get a load of json that includes the Auto Scaling group name

help to set up awscli(http://www.dowdandassociates.com/content/howto-install-aws-cli-security-credentials/)